# counting and permutation problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

i am having hard time figuring this out:

a) john,tom,jessie,sam,michael,and amanda want to split among themselves 100 apples
how many ways can they split the apples among themselves, if jessie cannot get more than 10 apples?

b)how many ways to split among 4 people exactly?

i am having hard time figuring if its permutation or combinations and how to apply the formula

any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**If I get this right for a)** : This is like putting $100$ apples in $6$ buckets, where you can put only $0,1,\ldots,10$ apples in one of them. You can treat each case separately. For example, if you give Jessie $6$ apples, then you have to give the $94$ remaining apples to the $5$ remaining persons. One way of counting this is to "put $4$ separators among the $94$ apples". For example, if x's are apples and | are separators, then

x|x|x|x|x...x

corresponds to giving $1$ apple to $4$ persons and the rest to the remaining person. Notice that we do not distinguish the apples one from another. The number of ways to place the separators is $\binom{94+4}{4}=\binom{98}{4}$.

Now summing up the possibilities for each of the $11$ cases, we find that the number searched is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{10} \binom{100-k+4}{4}=41\,669\,628
$$

Note that N. F. Taussig's answer is more efficient, though.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, x_6$ respectively denote the number of apples obtained by John, Tom, Jessie, Sam, Michael, and Amanda.  Since they split $100$ apples among themselves,

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 100$$

Since Jessie takes at most $10$, we have the restriction $x_3 \leq 10$.  Without that restriction, the number of ways the apples could be split is the number of ways of splitting $100$ apples into six piles, some of which may be empty. This is equivalent to the number of ways five addition signs can be inserted into a list of $100$ ones, which is

$$\binom{100 + 5}{5} = \binom{105}{5}$$

The restriction means that we must remove the solutions in which $x_3 \geq 11$.  Let $y_3 = x_3 - 11$.  Then

\begin{align*}
x_1 + x_2 + y_3 + 11 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 & = 100\\
x_1 + x_2 + y_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 & = 89
\end{align*}

The number of ways in which the apples could be split so that Jessie received at least eleven apples is

$$\binom{89 + 5}{5} = \binom{94}{5}$$

Hence, the number of ways the $100$ apples can be split among the six people in which Jessie receives at most ten apples is

$$\binom{105}{5} - \binom{94}{5}$$

**Note:**  If we assume that none of the piles are empty, then let $z_i = x_i - 1$, $1 \leq i \leq 6$.  Then the number of ways the apples could be split into six non-empty piles is the number of solutions of the equation 
\begin{align*}
z_1 + 1 + z_2 + 1 + z_3 + 1 + z_4 + 1 + z_5 + 1 + z_6 + 1 & = 100\\
z_1 + z_2 + z_3 + z_4 + z_5 + z_6 & = 94
\end{align*}
in the non-negative integers, which is 
$$\binom{94 + 5}{5} = \binom{99}{5}$$
The restriction that Jessie receives at most $10$ apples means $x_3 \leq 10 \Rightarrow z_3 \leq 9$.  Thus, we must eliminate any solution in which $z_3 \geq 10$.  Let $w_3 = z_3 - 10$.  Then the number of ways in which Jessie could receive more than $10$ apples is the number of solutions of the equation
\begin{align*}
z_1 + z_2 + w_3 + 10 + z_4 + z_5 + z_6 & = 94\\
z_1 + z_2 + w_3 + z_4 + z_5 + z_6 & = 84
\end{align*}
in the non-negative integers, which is 
$$\binom{84 + 5}{5} = \binom{89}{5}$$
so the number of ways in which the apples can be split into non-empty piles such that Jessie receives at most $10$ is 
$$\binom{99}{5} - \binom{89}{5}$$

Answer (score 0):

Generating functions would be one way to solve this: give each person it's own function $f(x) = 1 + x + x^2 + \ldots$, where the term $x^n$ represents that person getting $n$ apples. So we have 5 such terms, and one for Jessie how has term $g(x) = 1 + x + x^2 + \ldots + x^{10}$.

The required answer then is the coefficient of $x^{100}$ in the product $f(x)^5g(x)$. Now one can use binomial formulas (also for negative powers!), and facts like $f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}$ to get a formula for that.

The final question about splitting into 4 is unclear to me: do you mean that you select 4 persons out of the 6 and give all apples to those 4 (at least one each?). In that case you get ${6 \choose 4}$ times the coeffieient of $x^{100}$ of $(x + x^2 + x^3 + \ldots)^4$. But maybe you mean another interpretation.